# 'Overload resolution failed'. Is this not allowed? I want to avoid TypeOf

Tags: vb.net

I've constructed a simple example of the type of code I'm trying to write:

```
Interface Breakable
    Sub Break()
End Interface
Class Glass
    Implements Breakable
    Public Glassiness As Integer = 10
    Sub Break() Implements Breakable.Break
        Console.WriteLine("Smash!")
    End Sub
End Class

Class Paper
    Implements Breakable
    Sub Break() Implements Breakable.Break
        Console.WriteLine("Rip!")
    End Sub
End Class

Sub Main()
    Dim John As New Person
    Dim BreakableObject As Breakable = New Glass

    John.Mishandle(BreakableObject)
End Sub
```

In Person, VB won't compile if I write this:

```
Class Person
    Sub Mishandle(ByVal G As Glass)
        G.Break()
        Console.WriteLine(G.Glassiness)
    End Sub
    Sub Mishandle(ByVal P As Paper)
        'Did not rip the paper.
    End Sub
End Class
```

To get it to work, I need to do:

```
Class Person
    Sub Mishandle(ByVal Breakable As Breakable)
        If TypeOf Breakable Is Glass Then
            Dim G As Glass = CType(Breakable, Glass)
            G.Break()
            Console.WriteLine(G.Glassiness)
        ElseIf TypeOf Breakable Is Paper Then
            'Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

which is far less elegant if I have lots of classes implementing Breakable. Also performance is a factor in the real application I'm working on - Mishandle() will be called many times. I've done this sort of thing before in Java with Visitor pattern, So I'm confused why VB/C# is telling me:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Mishandle' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub Mishandle(P As Paper)': Argument matching parameter 'P' narrows from 'ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Breakable' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Paper'.
    'Public Sub Mishandle(G As Glass)': Argument matching parameter 'G' narrows from 'ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Breakable' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Glass'.
```

Any suggestions or am I destined to use TypeOf? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would Paper implement IBreakable if it cannot be broken?

Comment: It can be broken, but maybe by something other than a person. It is the first contrived example in my head. I just want to avoid having to use TypeOf and CType if I can (as I will need to access fields that differ on all of the concrete classes). I thought it was ordinary to just have several method signatures for each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision which routine to call has to be made SOMEWHERE, and if you use overloading, then the TypeOf call is being made for you, just invisibly. So yes, you're destined to use it. An interface has no code, so the decision which code to execute can only be made by finding out what class you're actually using.

If you're determined to both use an interface, and avoid using TypeOf explicitly, you could add a BaseObject function to your interface:

```
Public Interface IBreakable
    Sub Break()
    Function BaseObject As Object
End Interface
```

Then implement it in each class:

```
Public Class Glass
    Implements IBreakable
    Public Function BaseObject() As Object Implements IBreakable.BaseObject
        Return Me
    End Function
```

And use it for your call:

```
John.Mishandle(BreakableObject.BaseObject)
```

Fairly ugly, but it keeps your overloads as written...

Comment: What annoys me is that when stepping through the debugger, vs knows exactly what type the object is. it is just the compiler not allowing it. If I do this it works fine: Dim BreakableObject As Breakable = New Glass
        Dim MysteryX = IIf(True, BreakableObject, Nothing)
        John.Mishandle(MysteryX)

Comment: Just seems like all I need to do is confuse the compiler and then I can access the glassiness etc without casting

Comment: Actually, looks like I can just do Dim MysteryX As Object = BreakableObject to allow it to compile

Comment: The logical problem is that on the called side you want to take actions dependent on the specific object class, whereas an interface is used precisely to free the called code from having to know that. If your interface had an "ApplyRippingPower(Newtons As Integer)" method, your classes could decide the nature of the resultant catastrophe.

Comment: In the real application the interface defines methods getLatitude and getLongitude. It is implemented by Nodes and HopPositions which are positions between nodes. I kind of needed the routing algorithm to treat both classes the same for calculating distance, whilst being able to expand the search tree in their own particular ways. This second part didn't need them to implement the interface. I think after too much exposure to languages like Haskell that do pattern matching, I assumed this would be simple and I was just performing a syntax error.

Comment: I hear that. Using "Object" as you do in your solution below is obviously not type-safe, so a 'bad practice'...  From what you just said maybe the distance calc could be a function of a base object from which your Nodes and HopPositions inherit? Something like NodeLikeThing.DistanceTo(AnotherNodeLikeThing)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, things can be broken, just not by anyone or anything.  One way might be to reverse the interface and use `IFragile`:

```
Interface IFragile
    Property Strength As Integer

    Sub Break(power As Integer)
End Interface

Class Glass
    Implements IFragile

    Public Property Strength As Integer = 3 Implements IFragile.Strength

    Sub Break(n As Integer) Implements IFragile.Break
        If n > Strength Then
            Console.WriteLine("Smash!")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class

Class Rock
    Implements IFragile
    Public Property Strength As Integer = 10 Implements IFragile.Strength

    Sub Break(n As Integer) Implements IFragile.Break
        If n > Strength Then
            Console.WriteLine("Ka-POW!!")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, things are breakable, but based on another factor - strength vs the power applied.

```
Class Person
    Private Property Power As Integer = 7

    ' people cannot break Rocks, perhaps Elephants can
    Sub Mishandle(B As IFragile)
        B.Break(Power)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Test:

```
Dim John As New Person
Dim G As IFragile = New Glass

John.Mishandle(G)

Dim R As IFragile = New Rock
John.Mishandle(R)
```

`Glass, Rocks and People` are not all made the same, so perhaps the `Strength` and `Power` values are assigned or passed when created.  Refining the Interface with enough variables and it should become fairly flexible.

```
Dim Ziggy As New Person
Ziggy.Power = 1
Ziggy.Mishandle(G)             ' should not break, ziggy is a weakling
```

Likewise, give John a SledgeHammer and his Power increases to 15 and he can break rocks with ease. For more hard and fast rules - 'kittens cannot break X, Y and Z', I am afraid you may have to resort to `TypeOf` or `GetType`.

---

If you ever need to test for a certain interface:

```
If BreakableObject.GetType.GetInterface("IBreakable") IsNot Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("Fragile:  This is IBreakable!")
End If
```

Comment: However this will 'break' the paper. Maybe the example wasn't clear enough, I will edit. Thank you for the reminder to suffix the interface with I, as I always forget to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does indicate that my design isn't very good in my actual app which is about route finding. I think I have found a hackaround though

Answer (score 0):

I found quite a nice solution myself when trying to clarify my question:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim John As New Person
    Dim BreakableObject As Breakable = New Glass
    Dim MysteryX As Object = BreakableObject
    John.Mishandle(MysteryX)
End Sub
```

Works perfectly. If I make an extra class like Plastic and instantiate that instead, I get an AmbiguousMatchException.

Edit: I have just found that performance wise, it is much better to branch on TypeOf and cast somehow. the method above calls ObjectLateGet on the last line, which is very expensive.